# ChangeNotifierProxyProvider update parameter is nullable

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, dart-null-safety, flutter-change-notifier

I have a MultiProvider with a list of one ChangeNotifierProvider for AuthProvider (this a class with NotifierProvider) and a ChangeNotifierProxyProvider for <AuthProvider, AppProvider>.

[image: MultiProvider image]

As you can see, in the update closure of the ChangeNotifierProxyProvider i am getting an error that says:

```
"The return type 'AppProvider?' isn't a 'AppProvider', as required by the closure's context. 
The method 'update' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')."
```

And the type of parameter received in the closure is AppProvider?.

[image: AppProvider? type in update]

If I add the null check ! or conditional access ? to the object's update() method call, passes the linter bat throws a compile time error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
update: (_, myModel, myNotifier) => myNotifier!..update(myModel),
```

I got that from the ***question part*** of another stack overflow. It feels really wrong, but it seems to work and can't find a better answer.

The other post:
[ChangeNotifierProxyProvider is giving a possible null error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71835426/changenotifierproxyprovider-is-giving-a-possible-null-error)