# ChangeNotifierProxyProvider is giving a possible null error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

So, following the [ChangeNotifierProxyProvider docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProxyProvider-class.html) I have implemented the following:

```
   ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>(
      lazy: false,
      create: (BuildContext createContext) => AuthProvider(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<AuthProvider, APIService>(
        create: (_) => APIService(),
        update: (_, auth, api) => api..update(auth),
    ),
```

This is how it is recommend to implement it in the docs, however i am getting and error:

```
 The return type 'APIService?' isn't a 'APIService', as required by the closure's 
 context.
```

Would it be correct to change `api..update(auth)` to `api!..update(auth)`? Why was this not need in the example provided in the docs.